# How to Update/insert records based on WHERE clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking for query to `upsert`(update/insert) into Oracle table from `pandas` dataframe. After searching I got this `merge` statement which updates the values when the key is present else it will insert.

---

```
merge into table_A using dual on ( key_column = '123' )
when matched then 
update set date_column = TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-05 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), OR = 'MZM'
when NOT matched then 
insert (key_column, date_column, OR) values( '456',TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-04-05 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),'MZM')
```

**Solution I need**

*for update*

I want to `update` record based on the condition `max(date_column)` for that `key` which should be less than or equal to `30 days` from the record `date_column` I'm inserting.

*for insert*

I want to insert a new row for a `key` which is already present but the last available record .i.e `date_column` for that key should not be within 30 days.

**What I tried**

```
merge into table_A using dual on ( key_column = '123' )
when matched then 
update set date_column = TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-31 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), ORA = 'MZM'
where (select trunc(TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-05 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')) - trunc(max(date_column))days from table_A where key = '123') <= 30 
when NOT matched then 
insert (key_column, date_column, ORA) values( '123',TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-31 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),'MZM')
where (select trunc(TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-12-31 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')) - trunc(max(date_column))days from table_A where key = '123') > 30  ;
```

But it is not working :(.

I cannot do this from pandas because the data size is huge.

**Table recreation script**

```
CREATE TABLE "FDSMLDBUSER"."FDS_upsert" ("key" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, "date_column" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, "ORA" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE))


insert into "FDSMLDBUSER"."FDS_upsert" ("key", "date_column", ora) values ('123',TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-31 00:00:11.644', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),'MZM')
```

Can I do this using `upsert` keyword in oracle where the statement updates when `WHERE` clause is True or it will insert ?

I appreciate your help so much.

General Question:

Can there be more than one row for a key in the past 30 days in the table?
No, we should only have one record per key for past 30 days and that should be the latest one. if any key is older than 30 days then we need to insert new row for that key.

Can there be future dates in the table?
Fortunately No.

I use `executemany` method of cx_oracle to insert records to database where I convert pandas `dataframe` to `dictionary` to  enable column name inside it. Please find the code below:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(f'{db_user}/{db_pwd}@{db_host}:{dbport}/{db_service_name}',encoding='UTF-16', nencoding='UTF-16')
cursor = connection.cursor()
parameters = secondary.to_dict(orient='records')
query = config.get('FDS_APAMA_RAWDATA', 'fds_raw_data')
cursor.prepare(query)
cursor.executemany(None,parameters)
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0])
con.commit()
```

Comment: It sounds like we just look for the row for a key in the past 30 days and update it in case it exists or else we insert a row. In order to know whether that is so simple, here are some questions: Can there be more than one row for a key in the past 30 days in the table? Can there be future dates in the table? If there can be future dates in the table, what to do if I find a future date and a date in the past 30 days for the key? If there can be future dates in the table, what to do if I find a future date and no date in the past 30 days for the key?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Question updated with answers.

Comment: You cannot do this using `upsert` at least because there's no such SQL statement in Oracle. To compose a `merge` you need to compose a `select` statement that generates the result you need and then apply this statement as a megre source. As a brute force approach you may join the source table and use it's `rowid` in the `on` clause of `merge`

Comment: I see you are comparing the date with 2022-12-31 and 2022-01-05. So this is not about the current date? You want to upsert for instance 123 / 2022-01-05 and hence look for the key 123 and a date in the range 2022-12-07 to 2022-01-05 in the table? And it is guaranteed that for a key/date you want to uosert, there is no future date in the table, i.e. no row for, say, 123 / 2022-01-06 in the example? (And I still don't uderstand why your merge statement looks at two different dates, one in the past and one in the future. is this just a typo?)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Sorry that's a typo. No future dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the new data to the existing data and find whether a row exists within 30 days and then, if it does, use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to find the latest matching row and correlate the update using the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_A dst
USING (
  SELECT d.*,
         a.ROWID AS rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.date_column DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
  FROM   ( SELECT '123' AS key_column, 
                  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-05 00:00:11.644' AS date_column,
                  'MZM' AS ora
           FROM   DUAL ) d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_A a
         ON (    a.key_column = d.key_column
             AND a.date_column BETWEEN d.date_column - INTERVAL '30' DAY
                                   AND d.date_column + INTERVAL '30' DAY
         )
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID AND src.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
  SET date_column = src.date_column,
      ora         = src.ora
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (key_column, date_column, ora)
  VALUES (src.key_column, src.date_column, src.ora);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  key_column VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  date_column TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  ORA VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO table_a (key_column, date_column, ora)
values ('123', TIMESTAMP '2022-12-31 00:00:11.644', 'MZM');
```

The the row updates to:

> | KEY_COLUMN | DATE_COLUMN | ORA |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123 | 2023-01-05 00:00:11.644000 | MZM |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=93b257aa257c877a5731600723d2afa4)*

Comment: @MTO, Thank you so much! let me try on my application and update.!

Comment: @Vicky You have removed all the `AS alias` from the `SELECT ... FROM DUAL`  statements. For each bind variable you are including you need to give it an alias so `:HAWB` should be `:HAWB AS hawb` etc. Also, do not us `TO_TIMESTAMP` on something that is already a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If for the key a row in the last 30 days exists, you want to update this row, otherwise you want to insert a new row.

```
on ( key_column = '123' )
```

does not suffice to find that row. So, look up the table for a row macthing the key and the date range instead. E.g.:

```
merge into table_a 
using (select 123 as key, date '2022-01-05' as new_date from dual) src
  on (table_a.key_column = src.key and date_column >= src.new_date - interval '30' day)
when matched then
  update set date_column = src.new_date, ora = 'MZM'
when not matched then 
  insert (key_column, date_column, ora) values (src.key, src.new_date, 'MZM');
;
```

### UPDATE

As it shows, Oracle forbids columns in the ON clause of a MERGE statement to be updated. I consider this a flaw. But well, at least they raise an error.

A simple way to go about this is to use update and insert in a PL/SQL block instead of a merge statement: Update the row if it exists. Insert otherwise (when the update affected zero rows).

```
begin
  update table_a
  set date_column = :new_date, ora = 'MZM'
  where key = :key and date_column >= :new_date - interval '30' day;
  
  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    insert into table_a (key_column, date_column, ora) values (:key, :new_date, 'MZM');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know that Oracle forbids columns in the `ON` clause of a `MERGE` statement to be updated. I consider this a flaw. But well, at least they raise an error. So, we either need a more complex `MERGE` statement or a simple PL/SQL block with an `UPDATE`, then a check of SQL%ROWCOUNT and an insert in case the update count is zero.

Comment: Okay let me check! Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly.